# Determine if a WPF DependencyProperty value is inherited

Tags: wpf, inheritance, datacontext, dependency-properties

Does anyone know how to determine if the value of a WPF property is inherited? In particular, I'm trying to determine if the `DataContext` of a `FrameworkElement` was inherited from the parent or set directly on the element itself.

Answer (score 19):

[`DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource.aspx) will give you a [`ValueSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.valuesource.aspx), which includes a property for retrieving the [`BaseValueSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.basevaluesource.aspx). The `BaseValueSource` enumeration tells you where the `DependencyProperty` is getting its value from, such as inherited from parent, set via a style or set locally.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated after more digging**

There is a [`ReadLocalValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.readlocalvalue.aspx) method which is stupidly Read instead of Get so hard to spot in intellisense. (I think Apress' WPF book had a note about this actually.) It will return [UnsetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx) if the value hasn't been set.

```
if (ReadLocalValue(Control.DataContextProperty) != 
    DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
{
    // Data context was set locally.
}
```

If you for some reason need to get *all* locally set properties, you can use LocalValueEnumerator.

```
LocalValueEnumerator enumerator = GetLocalValueEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if (enumerator.Current.Property == Control.DataContextProperty)
    {
        // DataContext was set locally
    }
}
```

*And these two methods really make me wonder. Read instead of Get in the ReadLocalValue and a collection which you cannot iterate with foreach in GetLocalValueEnumerator. It's like .Net has these nice standard things which the WPF team just decided to ignore.*

Comment: I was using `ReadLocalValue` before to determine whether a value was set in a custom `Panel`. It lead to some really weird behavior where when a value was applied by a style, my panel would still believe the value wasn't set. Only when calling `SetValue`, would the panel start outlining my elements the way they were supposed to, although `GetValue` did return the values correctly. The proper way to go about this is as per [Kent's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/809480/590790), which gives you all of the information, rather than just the side effect (local value).